# With IxSet, can I build an Indexable wrapper around an arbitrary Indexable type?

Tags: haskell, happstack

What I'd like to be able to do is something like the following:

```
import Data.IxSet

newtype Key a = Key Integer
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Keyed a = Keyed { key :: (Key a), value :: a }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Indexable a => Indexable (Keyed a)
    where empty = ixSet $ ixFun (\k -> [key k]) : _somehow_reuse_indices_of_a_
```

The idea is that if some data structure is Indexable, I should be able to index a `Keyed` wrapping it by the same types (plus an index on `Key a`).

It should be easy to convert the functions passed to `ixFun` in the wrapped type's indices to work with `Keyed` instead of `a`: just compose with `value`. But I can't find any way of actually getting at those functions.

I also had a look at the ixset-typed package; the version of Indexable there actually provides a list of indices, rather than an empty IxSet. This would appear to be much more amenable to reusing the indices, but the "list of indices" is a custom type which doesn't export its constructors, so I don't appear to be able to get at them.

Have I missed anything that would support this kind of usage?

Answer (score 4):

The `ixset` library seems to conflate "key generation functions" with "indices", which makes the `Indexable` class a bit more powerful than the author probably intended. (In particular, `empty` is allowed to already have some elements in it -- which makes the name `empty` a bit weird!) You can fix this client-side with a little work, by introducing a new type that is just for the functions (and therefore *cannot* contain any elements):

```
data IxFun a = forall key. (Typeable key, Ord key) => IxFun (a -> [key])

ixFun' :: (Typeable key, Ord key) => (a -> [key]) -> IxFun a
ixFun' = IxFun

instance Contravariant IxFun where
    contramap f (IxFun g) = IxFun (g . f)

ixFromIxFun :: IxFun a -> Ix a
ixFromIxFun (IxFun f) = ixFun f
```

Then you can build some typeclass support, as in:

```
class IndexableFun a where funs :: [IxFun a]

-- turn any IndexableFun into an Indexable
defaultEmpty :: IndexableFun a => IxSet a
defaultEmpty = ixSet (map ixFromIxFun funs)
```

Instances of this class look very similar to instances of `Indexable`, but instead of `empty = ixSet [ixFun foo, ...]` you now write `funs = [ixFun' foo, ...]`. Now it is easy to write your instance:

```
instance (IndexableFun a, Typeable a) => IndexableFun (Keyed a) where
    funs = ixFun' (\v -> [key v]) : map (contramap value) funs

instance (IndexableFun a, Typeable a) => Indexable (Keyed a) where
    empty = defaultEmpty
```

You can even readily adapt the implementation of `ixGen` to this type:

```
 ixGen' :: forall proxy a b. (Data a, Ord b, Typeable b) => proxy b -> IxFun a
 ixGen' _ = ixFun' (flatten :: a -> [b])
```

Integrating this kind of approach into the `ixset` package itself would be a very nice touch, and shouldn't be too hard. Though do contact the maintainer first, as this could potentially be a somewhat invasive change: one would presumably want to modify the `Indexable` class itself rather than creating a convoluted extra-class-plus-default-instance setup like the one described above, which would not be backwards compatible.

Comment: Yeah, something like that was my backup plan. It doesn't allow me to reuse existing `Indexable` instances, but I don't actually have an immediate use case for that. You're right that it's come out rather nice; maybe I will see if I can get it included upstream.